# Profiling C++ program

Tags: c++, profiling

I have one function to profile for time. Actually the function shows time of `13222668` microseconds (13 seconds) when checked in main function. Then I started to profile different parts of function, minimal example is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
unsigned int match_time;
int func(){ 
  unsigned int i = 0;
  while(i < 20){
   high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now(); // if I start the time from here, it shows me just `827687` milliseconds (827 milliseconds). 
   //code....
    {
        //code...

        {
           //code....
        }
          //code....
    }
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
        match_time += duration;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
   }
```

If I start the time within the while loop , it shows just `827687` microseconds (827 milliseconds), but If I start above the while loop

```
 high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
 while(i < 20){
}
high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
match_time += duration;
```

I got  a high time `13222668` microseconds (13 seconds), which I doubt about.

Also when I checked the time for different statement execution, I get `0` time when printing (which I think is a printing problem) and the summation `match_time += duration;` of which shows  (827 milliseconds) during millions of runs.

I would like to know if my time profiling way is correct, and why the time varies within the while loop and outside loop (about outside loop time I doubt). Is my code hanging for some time due to any other reason.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42457605/841108) is a related question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, but I need to know why the time varies, I think there is some issue that holds my code for a while which is clearly shown if I use the time outside the while loop.

Comment: Repeat your benchmark several times. Execution time is not reproducible (because of many caches)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I understand, but the difference is so huge (12 sec)

Comment: So run your entire program several times. Execution time can vary a lot (e.g. because of I/O & page cache)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ok, do you feel any difference of having a time profile within the loop and out of the loop.

Comment: BTW, what operating system (& version), what compiler (& version), what optimization flag and what actual code are you benchmarking? How many times? Is your program multi-threaded?

Comment: When it says 13 seconds, does that correspond with your wristwatch or wall clock?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Linux `16.04`, `GCC c++17` , actually I am matching some 10 million strings of length 40 each. The function is running at least 180 million times and the actual time it takes to finish the job is `827` milliseconds which I check inside the while loop, and after finishing the while loop, the program seem to be holding for some time for some reason which I checked out of the while loop.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Yes

Comment: Then I would consider that `high_resolution_clock` an academic curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it just be that your `match_time` is not initialized?